# How to accept many github PRs from bots?

Tags: github

There are lots of small fixes posted by gh bots. I would like to mass accept the mergable ones. I can manually click stuff. I am writing more to pass the github standards.

Comment: Create a script using the github api that checks all prs, downloads them, tries to merge them and push them afterwards?